# Objective-C - Is NSMutableArray dynamic array?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, runtime

I was wondering how NSMutableArray is working under the hood.
Is it dynamic array or some kind of linked list?
My question is what is the runtime for:

```
addObject: //If is array it would be O(N)
insertObjectAtIndex: //Same here
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in understanding the implementation of `NSMutableArray` it is a toll-free bridged version of `CFArray` (mutable variant), and the source for `CFArray` is actually available from Apple [CFArray.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.10/CFArray.c).

The short answer is that it's a pretty complex structure of "buckets" which contain pointers to the elements of the array.